# Vue js route single URL

Tags: vue.js

vue route single url without after /

i want whole after / (relative url)

i want routing form components to another with out change the base url in may case the base url is '/' it's mean i want to route from component one to component two without change the url

```
export default new Router({
  mode: "history",
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "one",
      component: () => import("@/components/Three")
      // component: () => import("@/components/NoteMaser")
    },
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "two",
      component: () => import("@/components/Two")
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: Something in the formatting of your question went wrong. Please edit the question. Maybe you could also describe better what behavior you are seeing, and what you would want instead.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? and what's the error you are having ?

Comment: i want routing form components to another with out change the base url in may case the base url is '/' it's mean i want to route from component one to component two without change the url